How to find files of a certain minimum size?
With find, I will check if any file(s) with a minimum size of 1 byte exists in the directory in, and if not then exit.
I tried something like this, but it does not work
find ./in/ -type f -iname '*' -size 1c &> /dev/null
if [ "$?" != 0 ]
then
    echo file size is under 1 byte, aborting...
fi


With GNU find:
if (( $(find -H in -type f -size +0c -printf 1 -quit) )); then
  echo There is at least one non-empty regular file
else
  echo>&2 "Either there's no regular file or I can't read or search the directory, or all the regular files are empty"
  exit 1
fi

With zsh instead of bash:
if ()(( $# )) in/**/*(NDY1.L+0); then
  print There is at least one non-empty regular file
else
  print -u2 "Either there's no regular file or I can't read or search the directory, or all the regular files are empty"
  exit 1
fi

If in addition to making that test, you also want to get that list of non-empty files in an array, so you can process it later on in your script, in bash 4.4+:
readarray -td '' files < <(find -H in -type f -size +0c -print0)
if (( ! ${#files[@]} )); then
  echo>&2 "Either there's no regular file or I can't read or search the directory, or all the regular files are empty"
  exit 1
fi
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  something with "$file"
done

In zsh (with the additional benefit that the file list will be sorted; you can skip that sorting with the oN qualifier if you don't care about the order):
for file in in/**/*(D.L+0); do
  something with $file
done

Without the N qualifier, zsh will exit with an error message by itself if there's no match. If you want to output your own error message, you can do like in bash
files=( **/*(ND.Y+0) )
if (( ! $#files )); then
  print -u2 "Either there's no regular file or I can't read or search the directory, or all the regular files are empty"
  exit 1
fi
for file in $files; do
  something with $file
done

Some notes about your approach:

-iname '*' doesn't make sense, it matches files whose name (case insensitively!?) is made of any amount of characters, so except potentially for pathological cases where file names are made of non-characters, it should match all files so can be omitted.
-size 1c matches on files whose size is exactly 1 byte (c being for the older meaning of character from the time when characters were always made of one byte). You want -size +0c for files with at least 1 byte. -size +0 for files whose size rounded up to the next 512-byte unit is greater than 0 would also work here.
find returns a non-zero exit status when it encounters error preventing it from finding files, not when no file is found using the provided filter expression.
In modern Bourne-like shells, instead of cmd...; if [ "$?" != 0 ], you can use if ! cmd... (btw, != is for string comparison; for decimal integer number comparison (which would make a difference for instance when comparing 00 with 0, so not here), you can use -ne instead).
echo file size is under 1 byte, aborting... is not correctly describing what happens when no non-empty file is found.


Stéphane Chazelas, thank you very much. i reconized that you in some of my question give me very helpfull answers, many thanks! and a bonus too, zsh examples (-;
